# Is it possible and advisable to subclass a generator function?

Tags: python, generator, python-2.7

I frequently use a generator that returns a certain class. What I'd like to do is subclass the generator class so that I can use methods on it that are appropriate for generators that yield instances of that class. For example, one of the things I'd like to do is have a method that returns a generator that filters the base generator.

I want to do something like this:

```
class Clothes(object):
    def __init__(self, generator):
        self.generator = generator

    def get_red(self):
        return (c for c in self.generator if c.color=="red")

    def get_hats(self):
        return (c for c in self.generator if c.headgear)
```

The clothes class I want to treat as a collection of clothes. The reason I'm not subclassing a collection is that I rarely want to use the whole collection of clothes as is, and usually just need to filter it further. However, I often need the various filtered collections of clothes. If possible, I'd like Clothes to be a generator itself, as that's how I intend to use it, but I get an error when trying to subclass `types.GeneratorType`.

Comment: Some example code would be nice..

Comment: what is the problem? Have you tried to override the generator method? What happened?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A generator is something that behaves like an iterator, but the sequence it represents is, unlike a tuple or a list, generated lazily for each iteration step.  The common ways to create generators are by using generator expressions or with the `yield` statement; any other mechanism, if it exists, is black magic and you should stay away from it.

Therefore, you should forget about `types.GeneratorType` and inheriting from it.  You normally wrap or chain generators together.  You can do that with generator expressions, as you have in your example code or you can use the wonderful [`itertools` standard module](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html).

Answer (score 7):

```
types.GeneratorType
```

is defined as:

```
def _g():
    yield 1
GeneratorType = type(_g())
```

as you see, it is not a regular `class`.

Now, what makes a generator special?
Not much.
To make use of the `generator protocol`, all one has to do is to implement the `iterator protocol`.
There is a nice shortcut: you get the `next()` for free, when your `__iter__` is a generator.
And that's exactly how `collections.Iterable` is defined:

```
class Iterable(metaclass=ABCMeta):

    @abstractmethod
    def __iter__(self):
        while False:
            yield None

    @classmethod
    def __subclasshook__(cls, C):
        if cls is Iterable:
            if any("__iter__" in B.__dict__ for B in C.__mro__):
                return True
        return NotImplemented
```

So, just use that to build your generator.

Answer (score 6):

As pointed out in the comments to your earlier question, returning a generator expression is generally a bad idea. To quote [PEP 289](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/#early-binding-versus-late-binding):

> ...users should be strongly encouraged to use generator expressions inside functions that consume their arguments immediately. For more complex applications, full generator definitions are always superior in terms of being obvious about scope, lifetime, and binding.

In the spirit of the above, I'd suggest:

- make the main class iterable, by defining `__iter__` (which, in turn, can be a generator).
- define `get_xxx` as generators which iterate over `self` and `yield` specific values from it

Example:

```
class Numbers(object):

    def __iter__(self):
        for x in range(10):
            yield x

    def get_odd(self):
        for x in self:
            if x & 1:
                yield x


nums = Numbers()

for x in nums:
    print x   # 0 1 2 3...

for x in nums.get_odd():
    print x # 1 3 5...
```